# Python Flask - tracking a request for logging purposes

Tags: python, logging, flask

I'm not sure if I'm missing something obvious here as this appears like it would be a common issue.

I setup basic python logging to allow me add some debug during various parts of my Flask web service, but I realised if more than one request comes in at one time I won't know which request the logging pertains to.

How can I uniquely 'tag' each request that comes in, and modify the default logging format to include this tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's [a post](http://plumberjack.blogspot.co.uk/2010/09/configuring-logging-for-web.html) about doing this sort of logging for web applications in general; the approach should work with Flask in particular (the post was written for Armin Ronacher).

tl; dr: Use thread-locals.

Comment: You should mention that the blogpost you linked was not written by Armin, you're just referring to a post by Armin. Also, just linking to a blogpost isn't actually a valid answer on stackoverflow. At least copy an example in here.

Comment: I said it was written *for* Armin, so how could I be implying it was written *by* him? I'm not just referring to something Armin wrote, I provided an answer for this same question, which he posed. It's too long to post a simple example here, hence the link and tl;dr.

Comment: It is a long post and a little more complex than I needed, but the principals behind it are applicable for my needs.